# When did UDFs get introduced to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone out there remember in which version of SQL server UDFs were introduced?

EDIT: Thanks guys, looks like it was SQL 2000, I had thought it earlier.  Thinking about it now I do remember those days of doing nasty workarounds and just waiting for the next version...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214363(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226073(SQL.80).aspx) (link to white paper)

Answer (score 2):

They were introduced in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 1):

I think it was SQL Server 2000